# How to create a button with serverside event and clientside event?

Tags: modal-dialog, csom

I created a dialogWindow with a button OK. When someone click on OK, I would like to do some server side logic. After this I would like to close the dialog by returning: `SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK`

I try to add the OnClientClick but then the server side event is not firing. How to fix this?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="TestOK" OnClick="btnOK_Click" OnClientClick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, ''); return false;" CssClass="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

**OK** Button Control:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="TestOK" OnClick="btnOK_Click" CssClass="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" />
```

Just add this line at the end of the **OK** button click event method.

```
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup()</script>"));
```

i.e.

```
    protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // some logic server side

                // close dialog
    this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup()</script>"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works. The client side event is firing first and since you're returning false, it negates the server side event.

You could write a function on client side which would load when the page is loaded after the server event is fired. Or you can call JavaScript directly from server side.

Answer (score 0):

Call your code behind function on call back of **CommonModalDialog**

```
function OpenDialog() {
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.url = '/_layouts/mySolution/myPage.aspx';
    options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback);
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

---

```
function CloseCallback(result, target) {
    if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
        // Call your code behind code or button click event
    }
    if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My button is calling now only the server side event.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="TestOK" OnClick="btnOK_Click" CssClass="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" />
```

Inside the serverside event I do some logic and close the button as following:

```
protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // some logic serverside

            // close dialog     
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["IsDlg"] != null)
            {
                context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup()</script>");
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.End();
            }
        }
```